# Sql split entries into two entries if EndDateTime is the next day(after midnight)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have this query:

```
select 
    sth.Id,
    sth.CreatedDateTime, 
    EndDateTime = Lead(sth.CreatedDateTime, 1) over (partition by sth.Id order by sth.Id, sth.CreatedDateTime)
from 
    Sth as sth
order by 
    sth.Id, sth.CreatedDateTime
```

Which returns these results:

```
Id        StartDateTime                 EndDate                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2746743   2019-11-20 14:35:05.5841266   NULL                         
2746744   2019-11-20 14:35:05.5841266   NULL                         
3         2018-06-25 23:35:12.2799952   2018-06-26 09:57:27.8943163  
13        2018-06-26 09:57:27.8943163   2018-06-26 10:41:19.2973307
```

I have been asked to update the above query, split the row with `Id=3` into two rows.

Meaning: as you can see the record with `Id 3` starts at `23:35 and ends the **next day** at 09:57`

What I need it to split this record into two.

The first one should be from `23:35 -> 23:59`

And the one below should be from `00:00 -> 09:57`

> **If records span for more than one day. Nothing needs to be done.** Also the end solution should be able to work for a **history table**. **More than 3 million rows**.

So the record should result to sth like this

```
Id     StartDateTime                    EndDateTime
3      2018-06-25 23:35:12.2799952      2018-06-25 23:59:59.000000
3      2018-06-26 00:00:00.0000000      2018-06-26 09:57:27.8943163
```

I hope this makes sense!

All other records will yield similar results. There are records that do not need to be splitted.

Comment: What if a record spans more than two days?  What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Can we see the data you are using to build the result from your query?

Comment: @JMabee i have already provided mock data. Very small. Similar results are to be expected from the other rows. Do you need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result set in your question cannot be a result from the query you have specified (every `id` would have a `null` value for the end date).  So, I am interpreting the question as handling the situation where the end date is present and one day after the start date.

I would just use a lateral join:

```
with t as (
      select sth.*, CreatedDateTime as StartDateTime,
             Lead(sth.CreatedDateTime, 1) over (partition by sth.Id order by sth.Id, sth.CreatedDateTime) as EndDateTime
      from Sth as sth
     )
select t.id, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (startdatetime,
               (case when datediff(day, startdatetime, enddatetime) = 1
                     then dateadd(second, -1, dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, convert(date, startdatetime))))
                     else enddatetime
                end)
              ),
              (dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, startdatetime)),
               (case when datediff(day, startdatetime, enddatetime) = 1
                     then enddatetime
                end)
              )
     ) v(startdatetime, enddatetime)
where v.enddatetime is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=672054d2b9ee7b7fb9c0b3617fbded0e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I still get an error -> `Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: @panoskarajohn . . . Put a semi-colon before it.  A `with` needs to start a statement and SQL Server gets confused if there is an unterminated statement before it.